# On Weyl's majorant inequality

Tags: inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In [this](https://web.mit.edu/twang6/public/poly-roots.pdf) paper, the author uses the Weyl majorant inequality... (page 8, lemma 4.5)
I don't know how to prove this theorem and I can't find a simple proof. Can someone explain me a simple proof ?

Comment: what is it you don't understand?  That the modulus of eigenvalues of $A\in GL_n(\mathbb C)$ are log majorized by the singular values?  Or that applying a schur convex function to majorization gives the inequality?  I don't think there is a simple proof of the former.  The latter is a standard result in the theory of majorization, which takes some work to learn.  Based on your other question from an hour ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4453405/an-inequality-of-convexity it seems that you need to read up on majorization. Marshall and Olkin's book is the standard reference.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what I need to prove... Thanks also for the reference.